# Can this javascript code be rewritten in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use php to generate a table that has multiple links and divs like the one below, each with a unique id. Clicking the link shows the div. Can this be recoded with jQuery? The full code is pretty ugly with all of the backslashes and onclicks.

```
<a href = '#!' class = 'link' id = 'link".$id."' onclick = 'document.getElementById(\"box".$id."\").style.display = \"block\";'>click here</a>
<div class = 'box' id = 'box".$id."'>content here</div>
```

Comment: yes try your self in `jQuery` to convert and then you found any issue then ask here.

Comment: sure it can. what have you tried?

Comment: Where do you get the $id variable from?

Comment: This is not a pure javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not JavaScript making it ugly (and jQuery being pretty); it's the lack of separation of concerns that makes it ugly. Isolate your JavaScript, and activate it by registering a listener, not directly as string of code on your HTML (something that is just Not Done any more by any serious JS user).

This is perfectly readable, despite being "just" JavaScript:

```
<a href='#!' class='link' id='link<?php echo $id; ?>'>click here</a>
<div class='box' id='box<?php echo $id; ?>'>content here</div>
<script>
  var link = document.getElementById('link<?php echo $id; ?>');
  var box = document.getElementById('box<?php echo $id; ?>');

  link.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    box.style.display = 'block';
  });
</script>
```

On the other hand, here is your original code with jQuery:

```
<a href = '#!' class = 'link' id = 'link".$id."' onclick = '$(\"#box".$id."\").css(\"display\", \"block\");'>click here</a>
<div class = 'box' id = 'box".$id."'>content here</div>
```

Still ugly.

Comment: Won't work in older browsers. If you want to support them, stick with jQuery.

Comment: @Rudi: [IE8 is finally dead](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support). I don't care about older browsers, and you shouldn't, either. That said, I am not arguing against jQuery (I use it extensively myself), but for good programming practices (which was the real problem in OP's question).

Comment: When customers and their customers care for older browsers, you should do so too. OP uses jQuery and asked for recoding in jQuery..

Comment: @Rudi: I do provide a jQuery solution, as a contrast. The OP's question was basically "how do I make this prettier", and jQuery is an XY problem. All I am doing is illustrating the fact. (On the other hand, your solution, which I upvoted, conflates the two issues - separation of concerns and JavaScript->jQuery upgrade - which might lead OP to have a confused idea of what, exactly, jQuery is.)

Answer (score 4):

This is one way, change the HTML structure to this:

```
<a href='#!' class='link' data-box='#box".$id."'>click here</a>
<div class='box' id='box".$id."'>content here</div>
```

Then, bind only **one** event listener (instead of one per id) to the `.link` class. Use this code in an external JS file:

```
$('.link').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $(this).data('box');
    $(box).show();
});
```

Comment: I like this even better  - I failed to conclude from `$id` that this would be in a loop. I feel silly now. :P

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href = '#!' class = 'link' id = 'link<?php echo $id; ?>' >click here</a>
<div class = 'box' id = 'box<?php echo $id; ?>'>content here</div>
<script>    
$( ".link" ).click(function() {
    this.style.display = 'block';
    //this.style.display = 'none';
});
</script>
```